# Update image on faq for flags

Tags: support, status-completed, privileges, faq-update-request

**Update**
I have since updated the faq page for the meta since this post was written -- now the rest of the faq pages on the SE should follow suit, see update on bottom of this post.

*Now Back to the OP:*

---

On the [Faq Page for flags and flagging](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts) can we update the image to a more recent view of how it looks?

For example:

Question Flag:
[image]

Answer Flag:
[image]

---

### Update:

I edited the faq with one of the images above with the [given link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-wiki/3) in the comments below, but i feel it could be expanded more to include both image and what the differences are between them.

**ALSO** I only edited the meta faq -- it seems to be that **all** of the faq pages need to be updated with the new image(s) and I cannot do that -- it needs to be handled by a mod.

Comment: Feel free to [edit it yourself](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit-wiki/3) :)

Comment: The full page should be edited, as it is referring to three types of flags.

Comment: @Shadow, but which image to add, im just choosing one of them for now, i guess someone else can edit the rest

Comment: Nice! If you have time, just add both and explain the difference. :)

Comment: @Shadow -- see my **ALSO** statement that I just added to the OP

Comment: No mods need to be involved. Propagation of the privilege pages from MSO to other sites is done automatically and regularly.

Comment: @PopularDemand -- yea I was wondering how it was done because I saw no edit button on any other SE page. Also the info needs to be updated accordingly and maybe even add both images into the faq page.

Comment: @PopularDemand -- the page was never pushed.

Comment: sorry about that -- pushing the privilege wikis out from meta to all sites now.

Comment: @JeffAtowwod -- what about my suggestion to expand the faq wikis to include both popups and their explanations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been completed. Just posting an answer to get this off the "unanswered" list.